# poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

An ice-cream vendor’s sales follow a Poisson distribution with an average rate of 10 per hour. How much should his stock of ice-cream be at any point in time if he wants to be at least 95% sure that he does not run out of ice-cream in the following hour?

Comment: Welcome to Math. SE. When you ask a problem here you are expected to show your efforts. What properties of the distribution can you use ?

Comment: How is the inventory replenished? How many hours per day does he sell ice creams? are these important to set up an inventory system?

Comment: That is all the information given. I thought .pr(X<x)= 0.95 or more. x being the number of sales.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach, although I think it should be $P(X\leq x)\geq 0.95$ rather than $P(X<x)\geq 0.95$

Comment: Actually I suppose it depends on how you interpret the question, if it means ' run out ' as in never drop to zero, you are right, but if it means 'run out' in the sense that it reaches a point where he does not have enough stock to continue selling, then my answer is correct. But the bottom line is your approach is correct.